# ld : 0711-317 error : Undefined symbol: .kget_proc_info

Tags: c, ld, aix, kernel-extension

I am writing a kernel extension in AIX 6.1. I use the "kget_proc_info()" for getting info of a process. But there is a error when I make it:

```
1>ld : 0711-317 error : Undefined symbol: .kget_proc_info
```

And I use command "nm" to check this symbol：

```
#nm -A -X64 /unix  | grep kget_proc_info
/unix:    .kget_proc_info      T     3702624
/unix:    kget_proc_info       D    45909296          24
```

I can't understand the difference between ".kget_proc_info" and "kget_proc_info".
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure it it will help, but IBM provides a sample kernel extension and makefile at [Writing AIX kernel extensions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kernelext.html#listing3). You should verify you are linking against the same (or similar) libraries as the sample.

Comment: my linking libraries is same to what that article said.I am wondering my program miss a library corresponding to "kget_proc_info".

Comment: The capitol `T` tells you the code is actually there for a function called `.kget_proc_info`. The `D` tells you there's a variable in the initialized data section called `kget_proc_info`. Can you create an alias such that `KGET_PROC_INFO=.kget_proc_info`. Try the linker option [`--defsym`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002ddefsym_003d_0040var_007bsymbol_007d_003d_0040var_007bexp_007d-163).

Comment: By the way, when you have errors with ld or the compiler, please show the command being used.  I'm guessing you did not include the -bI flag but you might have and you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "link to" the kernel.  Instead, you tell the loader, "this list of symbols will be resolved by /unix" and that list comes from kernex.exp.  You do that with -bIkernex.exp.  The book will help.  There are also bos.adt.samples that give you (some very dated) examples.